# Match names with addtional prefix in PHP

Tags: php, tags, prefix

How can I match part of a name in PHP?

For example I have a form which takes the input from a user and my php code starts to count how many times its in a specific file. But in that file, some of the names have prefixes(ex. '[Prefix]Name') and the names that don't have a prefix have a white space (ex. ' Name2').

How can I make it so that the user doesn't have to enter a white space or the prefix and still get the count? Somehow to match it.

Comment: You could do this easily if the data were in a database. With a string/file you could use a `preg_match`, `str_pos`.

Comment: See PHP preg_match(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

Does this

```
$nameFull = '[Prefix]Name';
$nameToFind = 'Name';
$matched = preg_match('~' . preg_quote($nameToFind, '~') . '$~is', $nameFull);
```

solve your problem?